# Which character deaths trigger a game over?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I am playing on Casual mode, so I don't have permadeath enabled for my characters. If they die, I keep battling without them, but then I can use them in the next battle.

However, I noticed that when Chrom died, I got a game over instead of getting to continue the battle. I assume if my character dies,  I will also get a game over.

Are there any other character deaths that will trigger a game over in battle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with all of the Fire Emblem games, if the main Lord(s) die, there will be a game over. For Awakening, game over will only be triggered if Chrom or Avatar dies. If the other character dies, they will be gone forever in the Classic Mode (but you can still proceed with the game without them) or temporarily in the Casual Mode.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Does Marth's death trigger a Game Over as well?

Comment: @Nolonar No. You can still recruit Marth later :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually in free roam any characters death can produce a game over if they are the only unit on the field. You have no way of completing the map so it will trigger a game over.

Comment: That's not really the question though... and is pretty much inherently obvious.

Comment: @Amadeus9 Not really that obvious, I tried it wondering if it would just end the map. And the question asked what character deaths trigger a game over. Pretty sure this relates seeing how its a character dying causing a game over.

Comment: In a legalistic, overly literal way, yes, this does answer the question, but I strongly suspect the spirit of the question was more along the lines of "Is there anyone else that I need to take extra pains to keep alive?" Also, the question of whether it actually ends the map is purely academic - you no longer have a way to win the battle (or perform any actions, for that matter) so it's game over, whether it's "Game Over" or not.